# How can I create a table from an existing table in SQL but using cells from the old table as columns in the new table?

Tags: sql, databases

I have a table,

[image]

and I want to create a new table such as the one below (from the table above)

[image]

In SQL, I tried using the following commands. I am able to generate a table with only one column like this,

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT balance
FROM table1 WHERE balance='currency'
```

But if I try to do multiple WHERE clause's it doesn't seem to work.

I tried to do,

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT balance, category
FROM table1 WHERE balance='currency', category= 'date_valid_from'
```

I also tried using an AND statement but still no luck,

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
SELECT balance, category
FROM table2 WHERE balance='currency' AND category = 'date_valid_from'
```

This just returns empty columns of 'balance' and 'category' and not the specified Where clauses.

[image]

ALSO, the columns in the new tables, are the ones which I selected from the old table. i.e 'balance' and 'category' However I wan't the cells within those columns i.e 'currency' in 'balance' to be the new columns.

Comment: The correct way of using multiple WHERE clauses in SQL would be using the AND keyword like your second example. Are you sure you are getting the same error when using the second SQL statement?

Comment: It works but it returns only the columns, BALANCE and CATEGORY, which are just the columns and not the specified WHERE statements. it is not WHERE BALANCE='CURRENCY' AND CATEGORY='CATEGORY_NAME'. But simply returns, BALANCE and CATEGORY.

Comment: That is what you are requesting with the SQL statement. Any extra columns you want you have to add to the SELECT statement, e.g. `SELECT DATE, CATEGORY_NAME, BALANCE, CATEGORY FROM table1 WHERE BALANCE = 'CURRENCY' AND CATEGORY = 'CATEGORY_NAME'`.

Comment: This is exactly what I did but it does not work.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make the specified where clause the column, but it makes the selected variables as columns.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding on how SQL works, it will only retrieve the columns in the `SELECT` clause, not the `WHERE` clause. The reason that your second statement does not give what you want is that there is no row where the `BALANCE` column has the value `'CURRENCY'` and the `CATEGORY` has the value `'DATE_VALID_FROM'` (these values are on different rows).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this once, but due to some database settings I was not permitted to create a table with an SQL-command. Maybe something similar is happening to you? I had to copy the DDL code (Data Definition Language) for the table and create it, and then add the rows.

Maybe you could first copy and run the DDL. Should be available in whatever program you are using for the database.
https://www.educba.com/sql-ddl-commands/

Once the table is created, it will be empty. Then you populate it. Here is some example code.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3;
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE newtable AS SELECT * from oldtable.

Then delete the data that you don't want in newtable with the WHERE clauses.

Then you're good to go.

By the way this is not a data science question, please go to programming stackexchange.

Comment: Is programming to retreate/clean data not part of data science?

Comment: only if you believe the corporate spiel